# How to determine the instanteous velocity of an arbitrary point of a rigid body?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics

Consider a rigid body whose center of mass is located at $\vec{c}$ (3-dimensional) and an arbitrary point $\vec{p}$ that belongs to the rigid body, such that $\vec{r}$ is the vector $\vec{r}=\vec{p}-\vec{c}$. If the rigid body is moving with linear velocity $\vec{v}$ and angular velocity $\vec{\omega}$, how do I determine the instantaneous velocity $\vec{v_p}$ of point $p$, based on $\vec{r}$, $\vec{v}$ and $\vec{\omega}$?

I think $\vec{v_p}=\vec{v}+\vec{w}\times\vec{r}$ works only when $p$ is in the same plane as the motion, but what if it is not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The formula
$$
{\bf v}_p = {\bf v}_q+\omega\times ({\bf r}_p-{\bf r}_q)
$$
does *not* require any coplanarity. It is generally true.